# how to import python 2.7 static into python 2.3

Tags: python

There is a very old machine which could only run python 2.3 on it. But I need to run a script which contains something that only new python version could interprete, I have python 2.7 static installed. By using `./python 2.7 static` I could enter python 2.7 environment. But how can I run my script by only typing `python xxx.py` in the terminal. I tried to add `import python 2.7 static` in the script, but it's wrong. How am I suppose to do?

Comment: Try `from __future__ import *`

Comment: @RohitJain Thanks, but it still doesnt work

Comment: @manxing.. Which module you want to import.. You need to give the name..

Comment: Is there actually an executable named `python 2.7 static` on your computer, with spaces and all?

Comment: @RohitJain This line doesn't work in python 2.3: ´If any (s in a["show"] for s in("abc","efd"))´. It said the ´for´ part is wrong. I don't know which module I should use to solve this problem...

Comment: @Zack No, the name is python2.7-static, sorry

Comment: What does the age of the computer have to do with the Python version you can run on it?

Comment: This problem cannot be fixed by importing modules; you have to get the script run under the right version of the interpreter to begin with. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run your script by typing

```
./python2.7-static script.py
```

You can make life easier for yourself by running `make install` as root in the directory where you built Python; this *should* copy the program into `/usr/local/bin/pythonSOMETHING` (may not be `python2.7-static` anymore).  You can then put

```
#! /usr/local/bin/pythonSOMETHING
```

at the very top of your script, `chmod +x` it, and run it as

```
./script.py
```

This would not work if the name of the interpreter contained spaces, which is why I asked you about them.  Also, the `#!` line must be the *very first line of the file* or it won't work.

If you don't have root privileges, rebuild Python with this additional argument to `configure`: `--prefix=$HOME`.  `make install` will then install everything below your personal home directory, and you can use `#! /path/to/your/home/bin/pythonSOMETHING`.  Note that you *cannot* put `$HOME` in a `#!` line; you have to look up for yourself what it expands to (`echo $HOME`).